# Hosting a Flask app on IIS 7.5

Tags: python, iis, flask, iis-7.5

I'm trying to get a Flask app hosted onto an IIS server and I'm stumbling at the last section. Here are the steps I've taken so far:

- Installed [Python 2.6.6](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.6.6) and Flask 0.10.1
- Installed IIS 7.5
- Downloaded [PyISAPIe 1.1.0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyisapie/files/)
- Created a new web site in IIS

[image]

- Turned on "Enable 32-Bit Applications" for my newly created Application Pool.

[image]

- Created a Wildcard Script Map using the PyISAPIe .dll

[image]

- Created the following file and named it 'test.py'

```
from Http.WSGI import RunWSGI
from Http import Env

from datetime import datetime

from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True

@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/')
def catch_all(path):
    s = "Path: %s\nTime: %s" % (path, datetime.now())
    return s

def Request():
    RunWSGI(app)
```

- Used Chrome to go to localhost/test.py which returned:

[image]

The problem is this: my app only runs if you go to /test.py, but I'd like to run regardless of the URL. What do I need to do within IIS so that all requests, regardless of the URL, will use my flask app?

**UPDATE:** I've got it working, sort of. Here's what I did:

- Replaced the Request function in Http.Isapi.py with the following:

.

```
app_root = "my path"
sys.path.append(app_root)

from test import Request
```

- Used Chrome to go to localhost/test.py which returned:

[image]

I now have a new problem. When I go from my test app to the actual app I am greeted with the following traceback:

```
File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\connectors\pyodbc.py", line 50, in dbapi
    return __import__('pyodbc')
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

The issue isn't that I don't have pyodbc installed. My app works perfectly fine if it's booted up through the Flask.run() method.

Comment: You ever figure this out? I'm facing a very similar issue.

Comment: I'm afraid I never got it working. I eventually switched over the app to an Apache server. If your able to find an answer please let me know!

Comment: @JBolton:I am facing same issue and now thinking of using Apache. Can you please help me with how you setup Apache server to run python app which is using Flask

Comment: @OpenStack Sure. There are 3 important pieces: Python, Apache, and mod_wsgi (an Apache module). It's VERY important that all of them are either 32b or 64b. If any of the 3 do not match you will get all sorts of error messages. Add the following to httpd.conf file: "LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so". Then create a .wsgi script which sets the variable "application", ex: application = create_app(config). I can add more in a PM if you need it.